# How to make Postgres LISTEN async (non blocking) with FastAPI websocket?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, psycopg2, fastapi

I'm trying to make the Postgress LISTEN async with FastAPI so that the WebSocket connection is not blocking while waiting for Postgres table updates.

What I got so far:

```
router = APIRouter()

@router.websocket("/pg_notify")
async def get_notifications(websocket: WebSocket):

    await websocket.accept()

    conn = psycopg2.connect("*****")
    conn.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("LISTEN channel;")

    while True:
        try:
            conn.poll()
            while conn.notifies:
                print("Waiting for notification...")
                notify = await conn.notifies.pop(0)
                print(notify.payload)
        except Exception as e:
            print("exception triggered: ", str(e))
            await websocket.close()
```

This way an exception is raised on the conn.notifies,pop(0):

```
object psycopg2.extensions.Notify can't be used in the 'await' expression
```

Comment: `psycopg2` does not support asynchio. Have a look at [aiopg](https://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [psycopg3 (beta version, only)](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/)

Answer (score 0):

Finally the below works for me.

```
while True:
        try:
            async with aiopg.create_pool(dsn) as pool:
                async with pool.acquire() as conn:
                    listener = listen(conn, "channel")

                    task_pg_listen = asyncio.create_task(listener)
                    result = await task_pg_listen
```